# Python multiprocessing behavior on MacOS and Windows

Tags: python, windows, macos, multiprocessing, python-import

I'm creating a program that runs on a Windows PC and I'm having some problems with the multiprocessing module.

Let's say we run the following code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f():
    print('f running')


def main():
    p = mp.Process(target=f)
    p.start()

print('test print')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I run it on MacOS I get the expected result:

```
test print
f running
```

If I rin it on Windows I get:

```
test print
test print
f running
```

I understand that this behavior is because python imports the whole file for every new process, but is there a way to make it behave as in MacOS?

Thanks!

EDIT:

On my program I define some global variables on the top of the file which should never change, but when the process is started and it imports the file, those global variables get refreshed and they get new values, which is a problem.

Creating those global variables inside the if **name** ==... works on MacOS, but not on Windows. And on MacOS I wouldn't need to do it anyways.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f():
    print(v)
    print('f running')


def main():
    p = mp.Process(target=f)
    p.start()

print('test print')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = 'a variable'
    main()
```

Output on MacOS:

```
test print
a variable
f running
```

Output on Windows:

```
test print
test print
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ixg21219\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 313, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ixg21219\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ixg21219\Desktop\MP_test\test.py", line 4, in f
    print(v)
NameError: name 'v' is not defined
```

Comment: I think Windows people have to do some `freeze_support()` jiggery-pokery.

Comment: On Windows `mp.process`es are run by importing the main script, so anything at the module level in it will be execute each time this happens (in addition to it running when the script itself starts up)— that's why there's a need for an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard to prevent undesired recursion. See _spawn_ and _fork_ in the section [Contexts and start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('test print')
    main()
```

Comment: That works for a print, but my real problem is with global variables that I define on the top of the file. I will edit the question to add an example of where this causes me trouble.